# Field edits that are exported automatically in Cognito Forms PDF attachment?

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I edit the specific fields that are automatically attached in the PDF when selected in the notification email section? I want most of them but a few of the consents make the output crowded. Also, can I include any uploaded files directly into that same PDF to make one file?

Comment: I closed this question as it looks as a support ticket, not as a practical, detailed question. See [tour], [ask].

Answer (score 0):

We currently testing support for custom [PDF and Word merging](https://trello.com/c/6lmmtMMy) support in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), which would allow you to easily create custom merge templates in Word.  You even have the option to download and customize the default templates if you do not want to start from scratch.

Please [upvote](https://trello.com/c/6lmmtMMy) this feature and send us support request if you are interested in participating in the private beta.

In terms of including file attachments in the output, this is something on the drawing board but will not be in place for the beta.  Are you wishing to include Word/PDF documents or something else?  Do you just want them embedded as links or actually appear in the document?